# How to parse link url from a tag with sfref?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am trying to **scrape** website data and I can look for a tags that I want to explore.

However, this tags are like `<a title="Annex" href="https://www.myite.com/d…-3.pdf?sfvrsn=b3a84558_2" sfref="[documents|librariesProv…-4ef8-8b90-ae20b6b7590d">`

getting `a.href` just returns `https://www.myite.com/d…-3.pdf?sfvrsn=b3a84558_2` and that results in 404 page.

However, when I click on the tag on web page it opens pdf - the url is slightly modified.

How to handle these types of links in javascript. I am using js fetch similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50812705/9640177).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the exact <a> tag and the exact address that you are sent to ?

Answer (score 0):

`sfref` is an attribute that is used to resolve dynamic links. For example, when the `a` tag is cliked, the `sfref` attribute value is used to build `href` on the fly.

I assume you do not have the access to the logic used for link resolution.
The best thing you can do here is to tuse `Chrome Dev Tools -> Event Listeners` and find out the event where the link resolution happens.

Please keep in mind that different `a` tags might have a different resolution logic attached to them.