# Import html module with JS

Tags: javascript, html, import, module

New to coding and new to JavaScript.

I have a simple web page where I have a menu with different items (*e.g.,* results, and analysis). When you click on one of the item, say “results”, I want it to display within the same web page (without reloading) a piece of another HTML page containing the results, **which is in another file**. Why? Because the `results` content will be too large to write it in the `main.js`, so the `html` needs to be loaded from a different HTML file.

I am thinking (but there may be other ways to do it) of importing the `results.html` with JavaScript with an event listener. But I’m not sure how to do that. With an HTML module?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for your Problen:

1. use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to load your data when needed from the server and then render it in to the view.
2. use a [dynmaic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) with import(`...`) and load the whole module including your data and the view

my personal opinion is to go with 1. and just load your data when you need it.

Comment: With 1., when you say server, do you mean back-end server? I am only doing front-end for this task. Would it still work?

Comment: so where do you get your data from ?

Comment: I guess from the server then…?

Comment: Ok so I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50812705/16674436) to fetch my document, but the issue I have is that I get the following `[object HTMLDocument]`. But what I want is to have the content of the `HTMLDocument`. How can I get it?

Comment: You need to add the HTML Document to the dom. You can use `document. insertAdjacentHTML` to add the stringContent to the dom.