# fetching HTML with JS to replace part of the page

Tags: javascript, html, replace, module, fetch

So I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50812705/16674436) to fetch an HTML document, but the issue I have is that I get the following: `[object HTMLDocument]`.

What I want is to have the content of the `HTMLDocument`. Anyone knows how to do that?

Additionally, in my HTML module, do I need to create a new whole page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    this is some html text that needs to be <em>emphasized</em>.

  </body>
</html>
```

or can I simply put lines of HTML like this:

```
this is some html text that needs to be <em>emphasized</em>.
```

Comment: using `consloe.log(your_object)` will show you more ;)

Comment: Indeed, but I am not sure how to use it so that it can replace the page content... :(